# POST deployment commands on Elastic beanstalk environment using bitbucket CI/CD

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket

I am using bitbucket as my CI/CD to deploy to elastic bean environment . My sample configuration file looks like below

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  branches:
   dev:
    - step:
        name: "Zip File"
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install zip
          - apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
          - zip app.zip -r .
        artifacts: 
          - app.zip
    - step:
        name: "Deploy to dev env"
        deployment: dev
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
        - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.2.5
          variables:
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'ap-xxxxx-1'
            APPLICATION_NAME: 'exxxxs-xxxx-xxx'
            ENVIRONMENT_NAME: 'xxx-xxx-x-xxxxxx'
            S3_BUCKET: 'xxxxxxxxx'
            ZIP_FILE: "app.zip"
```

Now I need to install Google chrome using Curl after EC2 instance created by elastic bean environment. How can I add such commands. I have tried doing by adding a step to my bitbucket yaml file after my deploy step like this but got errors

```
    - step:
        name: "Install Google Chrome"
        script:
          - apt update && apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget 
          - curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash
```

What is the correct way of adding commands?

Comment: You want to install Chrome on that EC2 instance after it's running?

Comment: @Ivthillo yes . We are actually using Pupeeter for pdf generation, so for that chrome is our dependncy which we want to install

Comment: I would recommend to put the chrome install in an ebextensions script: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-configuration-files/ Here you can add scripts which can be executed before/after your app deploy (e.g. install chrome on your beanstalk)